# If $f\in\mathcal C[0,\infty)$ with $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)\in\mathbb R$ and $a>0$, find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^a f(nx)\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

**The Problem:** Let $f\in\mathcal C[0,\infty)$ be such that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)\in\mathbb R$ and let $a>0$. Compute
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^a f(nx)\,dx.$$

**My Thoughts:** Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Put $\ell=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x).$ I think that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^a f(nx)\,dx=\ell a.$$

Since $f\in\mathcal C[0,\infty)$ and $\ell\in\mathbb R$, we have that $\|f\|_\infty=\sup\limits_{x\in[0,\infty)}\vert f(x)\vert<\infty.$

Now choose $N(\varepsilon)\in\mathbb N$ such that if $n>N(\varepsilon)$ then $\vert f(nx)-\ell\vert<\varepsilon/a$ for all $x\in[\varepsilon,a].$

Then we have that
\begin{equation*}\begin{split}
\left\vert\int_0^a f(nx)\,dx-\ell a\right\vert
&\leq\int_0^a\vert f(nx)-\ell\vert\,dx\\
&=\int_0^\varepsilon\vert f(nx)-\ell\vert\,dx+\int_\varepsilon^a\vert f(nx)-\ell\vert\,dx\\
&\leq\varepsilon\|f\|_\infty+\varepsilon\ell+\varepsilon,
\end{split}\end{equation*}
and we have what we needed.

---

What do you think about my proof? Please do not post a solution to the problem, a small hint if you spot a mistake and want to post it is more than welcome.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: change variables u = nx

Comment: @OliverDiaz indeed it does, thank you Oliver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is valid. Just to provide a different perspective:

$$
\begin{align} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^{a} f(nx)dx &= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\int_0^{na} f(t)dt \\ &= a[\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{m} \int_0^m f(t)dt] \\&= a\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}f(m) \end{align}$$

The 1st step is from the substitution $t=nx$.

The 2nd step is from $m=na$.

The last step is an application of L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Typo in your last line.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Fixed!